# "List" object is not callable in Python

Tags: python, list, callable

I wrote the following code with Python but the terminal tells me "list object is not callable". Who know what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
c={"a": 10,"b":1,"c":22}
tmp=list()
for k,v in c.items():
    tmp.append((v,k))
print tmp
tmp.sort(reverse=True)
print tmp
```

Comment: Your code runs fine in python version `2.7.9`. Which version are you using? To find out, use `import sys` and `print(sys.version)`

Comment: unrelated: if you do not want to use a for loop, you can also create the list with a comprehension: `tmp = [t for t in c.items()]`

Comment: Your code works in python `2.7.6` and `3.4.3`

Comment: I would suggest `tmp = []` rather than `tmp = list()`.  This will also, incidentally, fix the error.  timgeb is correct, however, that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, because it conflicts with the built-in type.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code you have used the name `list` as a variable name and shadowed the built in list. Look for where you do that and choose a better name.
As a temporary solution you can issue `del list` before `tmp=list()`.